# <link rel="canonical" href='<?=$slink?>'>

Tags: php, html, seo

we have the following message in Google WMT and are concerned about a penalty,

"HTML Improvements
Duplicate title tags"

Your title provides users and search engines with useful information about your site. Text contained in title tags can appear in search results pages, and relevant, descriptive text is more likely to be clicked on. We recommend reviewing the list and updating the title tags wherever possible.

```
**Antalya Apartments For Sale**
/antalya_apartment.php
/antalya_apartment.php?bid=2&page=13
/antalya_apartment.php?bid=2&page=15
/antalya_apartment.php?bid=2&page=17
/antalya_apartment.php?bid=2&page=18
/antalya_apartment.php?bid=2&page=230
/antalya_apartment.php?bid=2&page=232
/antalya_apartment.php?bid=2&page=234
/antalya_apartment.php?bid=2&page=235
/antalya_apartment.php?bid=2&page=236
/antalya_apartment.php?bid=2&page=239
/antalya_apartment.php?bid=2&page=241
/antalya_apartment.php?bid=2&page=244
/antalya_apartment.php?bid=2&page=245
/antalya_apartment.php?bid=2&page=249
/antalya_apartment.php?bid=2&page=250
/antalya_apartment.php?bid=2&page=251
/antalya_apartment.php?bid=2&page=254
/antalya_apartment.php?bid=2&page=255
/antalya_apartment.php?bid=2&page=256
/antalya_apartment.php?bid=2&page=257
/antalya_apartment.php?bid=3&page=0
/antalya_apartment.php?bid=3&page=108
/antalya_apartment.php?bid=3&page=111
/antalya_apartment.php?bid=3&page=112
/antalya_apartment.php?bid=3&page=114
/antalya_apartment.php?bid=3&page=133
/antalya_apartment.php?bid=3&page=136
/antalya_apartment.php?bid=3&page=137
/antalya_apartment.php?bid=3&page=140

**Kas Villas For Sale**
/kas_villa.php
/kas_villa.php?bid=7&page=5
/kas_villa.php?page=1

**Turkey Apartments For Sale**
/turkey_apartments.php
/turkey_apartments.php?bid=7
```

Further we see a solution, to add the `rel=canonical` tag to the pages, but the page reads the head from the "HttpClass.php" file as below

```
<? 
class HTML 

{
function headers($Title,$url,$CssFile,$JsFile='',$charset='',$favicon='')
{
?>      
<html>
<head>
<title><?=$Title?></title>
<link href='<?=$CssFile?>' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script language='JavaScript' src='<?=$JsFile?>'></script>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=<?=$charset?>' >
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="<?=$favicon?>">
</head>
<?
}
}   
?>
```

How can we get it to pull the correct URL for the page it is on ?

Thanks!!

Comment: I think you misunderstood the message in webmaster tools. Canonical links will not help you here.

Comment: adding the current page number to the meta title would be a solution...

Comment: thanks. i have read the following here that suggests, http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.uk/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html

Comment: as the main page is /antalya_apartment.php how would we ad the current page number to the meta title here /antalya_apartment.php?bid=3&page=140

Comment: can you please suggest what to do about this, or should we not be concerned about the message

Comment: as i understand this is duplicate content + duplicate title

    http://www.turkish-property-world.com/kas_villa.php
    http://www.turkish-property-world.com/kas_villa.php?page=0  what to do pls advise

Comment: if you have the same content with different URLs, the canonical tag would help to prevent penalties for duplicate content. But since the page parameter alters the content, you should rather change the meta title accordingly. You can also "tell" google the function of the parameter in webmaster tools...

Comment: how can we fix this https://www.google.com/search?q=site:www.turkish-property-world.com%20kemer%20real%20estate#q=LUXURY+HOLIDAY+VILLAS+for+sale+in+Hisaronu+Fethiye+tourism+hotspot+%26+beach+holiday+resort.+2+km+to+the+turkish+mediterranean+sea%2C+1+km+to+restaurants%2C+cafes

Comment: in wmt we have already added 11 parameter settings 3 years ago

Parameter  URLs monitored  Configured  Effect  Crawl  
page  15,389  -  -  Let Googlebot decide  
Edit / Reset
bid  14,231  -  -  Let Googlebot decide  
Edit / Reset
KKId  13,102  -  -  Let Googlebot decide

Comment: the problem is we have 1.500 product listings but google has 20.000 pages indexed what to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your all pages it shows the same title ,

```
eg:
<title>Antalya Apartments For Sale</title>

/antalya_apartment.php
/antalya_apartment.php?bid=2&page=13
/antalya_apartment.php?bid=2&page=15
```

one solution would be use some unique title for each page..

you can take full page to a buffer variable and change your title , then print whole page ..

Comment: there is only 1 page /antalya_apartment.php where we can change the title. this link /antalya_apartment.php?bid=2&page=13 is generated by mysql that we have control over.

Answer (score 2):

The post you mentioned talks about duplicate content. You have duplicate titles, a completely different problem.

Canonical links are useful when you have a page that is accesible via the multiple URLs. For example, via an ID (www.website.tld/id/0815/) and a readable slug (www.website.tld/page/super-duper-sample-page/). You can then add a meta tag that tells the search engines which URL is the more important URL, that should be shown in search results.

Your problem is that you have multiple pages, with different content, but identical title. I assume that `Antalya Apartments For Sale` is the title of your search results. If you just add the page to that title, you should be good to go:

```
Antalya Apartments For Sale (Page 5 of 260)
```

This way every page has a unique title and google should be happy.

Comment: the problem is we cannot change every page title only the parent page title can be changed

Comment: any suggestion here https://www.google.com/search?q=site:www.turkish-property-world.com%20kemer%20real%20estate#q=LUXURY+HOLIDAY+VILLAS+for+sale+in+Hisaronu+Fethiye+tourism+hotspot+%26+beach+holiday+resort.+2+km+to+the+turkish+mediterranean+sea%2C+1+km+to+restaurants%2C+cafes

Comment: I gave you a possible solution. Your question cannot be answered with the code you provided.

Comment: thanks for the help. i wish we could change the title on each page produced but there is only 1 page we have access to, to change title antalya_apartment.php,